# Wait till Windows Media player ends?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, loops, media-player

I'm so close to complete my program but I have a question.
Is there anyway that I can pause the loop till All files in Windows Media Player has been played.
like in process example:

```
                            process.WaitForExit();
                            while (!process.HasExited)
                                Thread.Sleep(500);
```

Code:

```
        private bool listbox3job()
        {
            AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer axWmp =
wfh.Child as AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer;
            DateTime? start = starttid2.Value;
            DateTime? end = sluttid2.Value;
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

            if (start == null || end == null)
            {
            }
            else if (now >= start.Value && now <= end.Value)
            {
                while (DateTime.Now < end.Value) // Loops till DateEndTime.
                {
                    foreach (var selected in listBox3.Items) // Each file in ItemList.
                    {
                        string s = selected.ToString();

                        if (listBox3Dict.ContainsKey(s))
                        {
                            axWmp.URL = (listBox3Dict[s]); //Where all WMP files starts
                        }
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Anyone?? Really need help with this one.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to handle the PlaystateChanged event. [msdn PlaystateChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562460%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) 
There you can exactly determine when the playback of the current media starts and ends.

I would also suggest you to use (embedd if you use Windows Forms) the WPF [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.aspx) as it is much easier to use and more stable.